# Parenthesis missing for close votes count in mobile view

Tags: bug, design, vote-to-close, mobile-web

The close count in the desktop view has the parenthesis but where as the mobile web view doesn't.

**In Desktop view**

[image]

**In Mobile view**

[image]

Comment: Not sure it is a bug, looks more like part of the chosen design.